# convert VBA to OpenOffice Calc Basic. Impossible?

Tags: excel, vba, openoffice-calc

Interested in the issue, it's really possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about automatic conversion? Of course it's possible to port manually from one to the other, there is a tutorial / reference here: http://documentation.openoffice.org/HOW_TO/various_topics/VbaStarBasicXref.pdf

Comment: i have one xls file with vba macros and i try open this file in OpenOffice Calc. But macros run with error. so i try find automatic convertor, i find this: http://www.business-spreadsheets.com/vba2oo.asp , but i not have success result.